# Impact of user account deletion on Availability in CVSS v3.1?

Tags: cvss

First, some excerpts from the CVSS official docs.

According to [CVSS 3.1 Specification](https://www.first.org/cvss/specification-document):

> While the Confidentiality and Integrity impact metrics apply to the
> loss of confidentiality or integrity of data (e.g., information,
> files) used by the impacted component, **this metric refers to the loss
> of availability of the impacted component itself, such as a networked
> service (e.g., web, database, email). Since availability refers to the
> accessibility of information resources, *attacks that consume network
> bandwidth, processor cycles, or disk space* all impact the availability
> of an impacted component.**

According to [CVSS 3.1 User Guide](https://www.first.org/cvss/user-guide):

> The Confidentiality and Integrity metrics refer to impacts that affect
> the data used by the service. For example, web content that has been
> maliciously altered, or system files that have been stolen. The
> **Availability impact metric refers to the operation of the service.
> That is, the Availability metric speaks to the performance and
> operation of the service itself – not the availability of the data.**
> Consider a vulnerability in an Internet service such as web, email, or
> DNS that allows an attacker to modify or delete all web files in a
> directory. The only impact is to Integrity, not Availability, as the
> web service is still functioning – it just happens to be serving back
> altered content.

What I could presume according to those statements was (especially by considering the given examples such as "attacks that consume network bandwidth, processor cycles, or disk space"), user accounts should be treated as data and thereby deletion, disabling, or locking of those will have an impact on Integrity not on Availability.

But that doesn't sound right. Deleting the accounts means, system won't be *available* to be used by valid users. In that sense, shouldn't user accounts be treated as resources that are needed for the operation of the service, rather than just data?

Comment: Flip your question around; how does "deletion, disabling, or locking" apply as an Integrity issue? In these cases, the account maintains integrity, but they are not available.

Comment: I'm quite OK with what shroeder said but I think it's quite subjective. If an account is deleted technically the system is no longer available from a "customer" point of view.

Comment: @schroeder just to make sure i understood your comment properly, you believe account deletion should be treated as having an impact on Availability in CVSS?

Comment: If my account is deleted, I can no longer use the service.

Comment: @drox I actually just wanted you to consider the question. You said that it was Integrity, but ***why***? I can see a case being made for either or both Integrity and Availability depending on context *and the effect*. On it's face, it appears to be more clearly an Availability issue, but if the account was deleted/disabled/locked *as a result of an Integrity issue* then the context changes.